# Dimension mismatch while using Pytorch LSTM module

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, lstm

I have a pytorch pretrained model from which I am generating features/embedding for some input sentences. The features are essentially `torch` object. For example a sample `input_embedding` (a list of torch objects) for one sentence looks like below

```
[tensor([-0.8264,  0.2524], device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<SelectBackward>)]
```

Now, I want to pass this embedding through a custom model which is fundamentally a bi-directional LSTM:

```
def custom_model(input_embedding):
    #initialize BiLSTM
    bilstm = torch.nn.LSTM(input_size=1, hidden_size=1, num_layers=1, batch_first=False, bidirectional=True)
    #feed input to bilstm object
    bi_output, bi_hidden = bilstm(input_embedding)
    # more code ....
    return F.softmax(x)
```

I wanted to pass my `input_embedding` to this custom model to get the prediction output like below:

```
for item in input_embedding:
    y_pred = biLSTM_single_sentence_student_model(item)
```

But it is throwing error on the `bi_output, bi_hidden = bilstm(input_embedding)` line saying:

`IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)`

Most likely I am not defining the `bilstm` object properly due to my lack of understanding of [Pytorch nn.LSTM input](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/understanding-lstm-input/31110/5).

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input to [LSTM](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=lstm#torch.nn.LSTM) must be a 3d tensor of shape `(seq_len, batch, input_size)`. In your example, you are basically providing a 2d tensor of shape `seq_len, input_size` as you mentioned, `[-0.8264,  0.2524]` is one example sentence.

So, you can modify your example as follows.

```
# a list of 2 sentences
input_embedding = [
    torch.FloatTensor([[-0.8264],  [0.2524]]),
    torch.FloatTensor([[-0.3259],  [0.3564]])
]
for item in input_embedding:
    # item is a 2d tensor of shape `seq_len, input_size`
    # so, we unsqueeze it to make it 3d `seq_len, 1, input_size` where batch_size = 1
    y_pred = custom_model(item.unsqueeze(1))
    print(y_pred.size()) # 2, 1, 2
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

### LSTM Basics

**Note:** The below explanation is for pytorch when `batch_first=True`

Lets start by looking at how an unrolled LSTM looks like

[image]

Above shown is a stacked unidirectional LSTM.

- A stacked LSTM has multiple LSTM cells stacked one over the other. The number of stacked LSTMs is defined by number of layers (`no:of_layers`).
- LSTM cell is unrolled over the time on the input. The number of unrollings is determine by the length of the input sequence (`seq_len`)
- Each input to an unrolled LSTM is a vector of certain size (as defined by `input_size`)
- Output of unrolled LSTM is a vector of certain size (as defined by `hidden_size`). This is calculated using a serious of operation on input, last hidden state and the current cell state.
- Normally training happens on a batch of data (forward prop and backward prop) rather then for single input sample at a time.

#### Define

So to use\define an LSTM we need to define below information

1. Input: of size `batch_size x seq_len x input_size`
2. output: of size `batch_size x seq_len x hidden_size`

LSTM is defined with size of the vector given to the unrolled LSTM cell and the output vector size returned from the unrolled LSTM cell

```
lstm = nn.LSTM(2, 5, batch_first=True)
```

defines a LSTM which takes in a vector or size 2 (per unrolling) and return a vector of size 5 (per unrolling)

#### Unrolling

We calculate the output of LSTM by feeding it a batch of data and by giving in an optional initial hidden state and cell state.

Initial Hidden state: In bidirectional LSTM one LSTM roles from left to right and another from right to left.  So initial hidden state is of size `no:of_layers X no:of_directions X hidden_size`. This is exactly same for the cell state too.

Now lets create the data for a `batch_size=32` which has a sequence of 10 and vector of 2 per input.

```
X = torch.randn(32,10,2)
```

The optinal hidden state and cell state

```
h = torch.randn(1*1, 32, 5)
c = torch.randn(1*1, 32, 5)
```

Finally lets unroll and calcualte the output

```
out, hidden = lstm(X, (h,c))
```

### Your problem

In your case you have a list of tensors each tensor corresponding to the features of a sample. We need to convert it into a tensor of shape `batch_size x seq_len x input_size` where `batch_size` is number of tensors `seq_len=2` and `input_size=1`

#### Working code

```
class CustomModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomModel, self).__init__()

        input_size = 1

        hidden_size = 6
        target_size = 2

        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, batch_first=True) 
        self.linear = nn.Linear(hidden_size, target_size)

    def forward(self, X):
        out, hidden = self.lstm(X)
        y_hat = self.linear(hidden[0][0])
        y_hat = F.log_softmax(y_hat, dim=1)
        return y_hat


data = [torch.randn(2) for i in range(100)]
X = torch.stack(data)
X = X.unsqueeze(-1)

model = CustomModel()


for epoch in range(1):  
        tag_scores = model(X)  
        print (tag_scores)
```

Comment: great explanation @mujjiga, but I am not sure how you are coming up with the `batch_size` in the sample code. Also I understand what `seq_len` means but I don't see you using it in the code after defining it in the constructor. What am I missing?

Comment: @nad `seq_len` is with respect to input. LSTM will unroll based on the length of input supplied. So we dont need to define it in LSTM but it is inferred form the size of input. Batch length is used during training to create a batch of data, so again not needed for LSTM definition. I have updated the code (they were left over lines of the other example I had).